# Can publications on research conducted before I started my tenure-track position count towards tenure? Do they need to have my new affiliation?

Tags: publications, tenure-track, affiliation

I am joining a new school as a TT Assistant Professor soon and I know I will be on the 'tenure clock' and have to publish manuscripts in certain prestigious journals. I have two pending publications in high quality journals that would certainly help a lot with this. In both, most of the research was done before I joined the new school, but will be published after I officially join.

- How do these papers get counted? Do they need the new affiliation in order to count towards tenure?
- Is it acceptable to change my affiliation to the new school?

Comment: They will probably count, but you really need to ask your department chair or some other knowledgeable person at your new institution about this. It is pointless to speculate, you need an authoritative answer about such an important question.

Comment: Seconding @DanRomik .  That's going to depend on each university's policies (some will count papers published during graduate school, for instance, and others won't).

Comment: You can try negotiating this.  Definitely one should find out before signing a contract.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not in a position to renegotiate this since I signed the contract a few months ago. This may be helpful for others though so thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is substantial variation between universities, and to an extent departments within a university, about what counts towards tenure. The best way to find out is to ask your department chair, a mentor, or someone on the tenure and promotions committee about what counts.

That said, there are ethics regarding what affiliations should be listed on publications. If your "pending publications" are in press or far along the review process, it would be unethical to switch your affiliation. If you are still writing the manuscript, or the reviews require a major revision, and you do additional work while at your new university, then it would be appropriate to add an additional affiliation.